# How to write a parse for EBNF syntax?

Tags: parsing, ebnf

I receive a task to parse a text which conforms to EBNF syntax. Is there any tool/library I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is the standard tool for parsing EBNF.

See [Good parser generator (think lex/yacc or antlr) for .NET? Build time only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257268/1583) here on SO.