# parse code with reqular expressions

Tags: regex, parsing

I try to implement a parser and below statements should be found

```
if @loglevel < 1 or
   @loglevel > 3
begin
   dothis
   dothat
end
else
   foo
   makethis
end
```

The parser should work with regular expressions and should return

**condtion part** 
   (=> @loglevel < 1 or @loglevel > 3)

**then part**
(=> everthing between begin dothis dothat end)

**else part**
(=> everthing between else begin ....end)

Of course it should be possible that the code do not contain the else part

Is it possible to do this with on or more reqex's expressions or should I implement a sequenciell "readline parser"

Comment: Do a sequential parser. Using regular expression for non-trivial grammars is asking for trouble. The primary reason is the (presumed) possibility of nesting your statements.

Comment: Adding to what Amadan said, using regular expressions is only sane when you have very regular patterns as input. If nesting, recursion, etc were not allowed, regular expressions might work for a non-recursive, finite grammar. It's still a challenge though.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct, you should not use regular expressions for parsing, [here](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html) is an article describing why it's a bad idea.

You could look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for help with your parser. There are is a question here [with some info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9645544/966097)